# Mark an option as selected

Tags: php, mysql

I am populating a dropdown menu with data in a database, using this code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_gallery";
$execute = mysqli_query($link, $query); 

$results = mysqli_num_rows($execute);

if ($results!=0) {
    echo '<label>The galleries are: ';
    echo '<select id="galleries" name="galleries">';
    echo '<option value=""></option>';

    for ($i=0; $i<$results; $i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute);
        $name = htmlspecialchars($row['galleryName']);

        echo '<option value="' .$name. '">' .$name. '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</label>';
}
```

I want to add the `selected=selected` to the option selected and then use that option in another query, but I have problem adding the selected tag in the actual selected entry.

**More INFO:**

I am using dropzone.js to upload images, and I want to select the category on the fly. The category has to be selected from the dropdown menu and used in the INSERT query.

Comment: How do you know which is selected?

Comment: What have you written for "selected=selected"

Comment: That is the problem. I am stacked on how to write it!

Comment: You are populating the select box with data but you don't have a specific result to determine which option must be selected?

Comment: Based on the pressed entry in the dropdown menu. Store in a variable and the use where needed!

Example with bug and old jQuery: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NeilHanlon/dFwFm/)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a form with POST then the code is

```
$selected = "";
if($_POST['galleries']==$name) $selected=" selected='selected'";
echo '<option value="' .$name. '"'.$selected.'>' .$name. '</option>';
```

Comment: I am using dropzone.js to upload images, and I want to select the category on the fly. The category has to be selected from the dropdown menu and used in the INSERT query.

Comment: so you dont need the selected option from that code, you need to be used at insert query?

Comment: I thought to use jquery also but then I do not have the idea how to get the selected variable from PHP.

This is the bugged [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NeilHanlon/dFwFm/) with old jquery!

Comment: I am still working hard on this, and now I can write selected in the SELECT list near the selected field. the only problem as you can see in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFeast/JMV9a/) the selected attribute is not removed from the old....any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example try this,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_gallery";
$execute = mysqli_query($link, $query); 

$results = mysqli_num_rows($execute);

if ($results!=0) {
    echo '<label>The galleries are: ';
    echo '<select id="galleries" name="galleries">';
    echo '<option value=""></option>';

    for ($i=0; $i<$results; $i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute);
        $name = htmlspecialchars($row['galleryName']);

if( $i == 1 )
{
$sel = 'selected="selected"';
}
else
{
$sel = '';
}
        echo '<option value="' .$name. '"'. $sel .' >' .$name. '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</label>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a specific option then you are going to have a variable containing that specific option example:

```
$conditionalName = "Mark";

 $query = "SELECT * FROM my_gallery";
    $execute = mysqli_query($link, $query); 

    $results = mysqli_num_rows($execute);

    if ($results!=0) {
        echo '<label>The galleries are: ';
        echo '<select id="galleries" name="galleries">';
        echo '<option value=""></option>';

        for ($i=0; $i<$results; $i++) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute);
            $name = htmlspecialchars($row['galleryName']);

            echo '<option value="' .$name. '"'; if($name=$conditionalName){ echo ' selected=selected';} echo '>'. $name. '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        echo '</label>';
}
```